# ffmpeg.exe working on local windows system. But does not work on online linux server

Tags: php, windows, linux, ffmpeg

I have downloaded ffmpeg.exe file with php using exec function. It works fine on local system of windows with xamppp and converts videos to flv format. But now I have uploaded files on server and it does not work at all and that server is linux server.
Can any body help me whats wrong or how can i solve this issue?

Comment: please look at your log files on the linux server and post any errors you see.

Comment: ffmpeg might not installed on your server, if your server is of hosting company, than surely ffmpeg is not installed.

Answer (score 3):

exe files are not linux executables.. just call ffmpeg program on linux. (check if its installed)